# How to store a value in a variable and load that variable as a new column in a file using a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to read a csv file and store a value in a variable and use that variable value to be written as a last column of the same file.

```
@echo off 
del three.txt 
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
set N=1 
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (combined.csv) do ( 
  set /a N+=1 
  if !N! equ 7 >> three.txt echo.%%a 
  ) 
for /f "tokens=1-10 delims=, " %%a in (three.txt) do ( 
  SET x=%%g 
) 
echo %x% >> three.txt 
endlocal
```

I want the last read value which is in three.txt to be stored in a variable and use the same to be print a column in the same file. Below  is the data in combined.csv

```
,Safaricom,,,,Channel to subscriber transfer,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,Report code :,,C2STRANSFER02,
,Network name    :,,Safaricom,,,,,,,Service:,,,ALL,
,Zone :,,Safaricom    Zone,,,,,,,Category :,,,ALL,
,Domain :,,Dealer Domain,,,,,,,User    name :,,,ALL,
,Dated :,,02/12/15 08:56:46,,,,,,,Date :,,,01/12/15,
,Sl. No.,Transaction ID,,Request source,User name,Sender mobile number,Receiver mobile number,Service   
   class,Service,Sub-service,Requested amount,Credit amount,Bonus,Process fee
,Transfer,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,1,R151201.2053.140019,,EXTGW,GAZETI LIMITED,700945609,700648591,PREPAID,Customer Recharge,Airtime,130.00,130.00,0.00,0.00
,2,R151201.2243.140015,,EXTGW,GAZETI LIMITED,700945609,727783637,PREPAID,Customer Recharge,Airtime,50.00,50.00,0.00,0.00
```

I had read the date 01/12/15 from the combined.csv I want to store it in a variable and store the same date for all the records as a last column.

Comment: I had read the date 01/12/15 from the combined.csv I want to store it in a variable and store the same date for all the records as a last column. Does it makes sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want to read the date from `combined.csv` and add it as a new last column to a file `three.txt`.

Your question is not very clear (even after several edits) and your batch file is broken in many different ways.

Please try the following batch file (example.cmd):

```
@echo off 
setlocal
if exist three.txt del three.txt 
rem get the date "01/12/15"
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1-10 usebackq delims=," %%a in (`type combined.csv`) do ( 
  set _date=%%d
  goto :next
  )
:next
rem add the date to the end of every line and output to "three.txt"
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in (`type combined.csv`) do ( 
  echo %%a,%_date%>>three.txt
  )
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>type combined.csv
,Safaricom,,,,Channel to subscriber transfer,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,Report code :,,C2STRANSFER02,
,Network name    :,,Safaricom,,,,,,,Service:,,,ALL,
,Zone :,,Safaricom    Zone,,,,,,,Category :,,,ALL,
,Domain :,,Dealer Domain,,,,,,,User    name :,,,ALL,
,Dated :,,02/12/15 08:56:46,,,,,,,Date :,,,01/12/15,
,Sl. No.,Transaction ID,,Request source,User name,Sender mobile number,Receiver mobile number,Service class,Service,Sub-service,Requested amount,Credit amount,Bonus,Process fee
,Transfer,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,1,R151201.2053.140019,,EXTGW,GAZETI LIMITED,700945609,700648591,PREPAID,Customer Recharge,Airtime,130.00,130.00,0.00,0.00
,2,R151201.2243.140015,,EXTGW,GAZETI LIMITED,700945609,727783637,PREPAID,Customer Recharge,Airtime,50.00,50.00,0.00,0.00

F:\test>example.cmd

F:\test>type three.txt
,Safaricom,,,,Channel to subscriber transfer,,,,,,,,,,01/12/15
,,,,,,,,,,,Report code :,,C2STRANSFER02,,01/12/15
,Network name    :,,Safaricom,,,,,,,Service:,,,ALL,,01/12/15
,Zone :,,Safaricom    Zone,,,,,,,Category :,,,ALL,,01/12/15
,Domain :,,Dealer Domain,,,,,,,User    name :,,,ALL,,01/12/15
,Dated :,,02/12/15 08:56:46,,,,,,,Date :,,,01/12/15,,01/12/15
,Sl. No.,Transaction ID,,Request source,User name,Sender mobile number,Receiver mobile number,Service class,Service,Sub-service,Requested amount,Credit amount,Bonus,Process fee,01/12/15
,Transfer,,,,,,,,,,,,,,01/12/15
,1,R151201.2053.140019,,EXTGW,GAZETI LIMITED,700945609,700648591,PREPAID,Customer Recharge,Airtime,130.00,130.00,0.00,0.00,01/12/15
,2,R151201.2243.140015,,EXTGW,GAZETI LIMITED,700945609,727783637,PREPAID,Customer Recharge,Airtime,50.00,50.00,0.00,0.00,01/12/15
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [goto](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) - Direct a batch program to jump to a labelled line.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.

Comment: @user2500677 Do you need more help? If this was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept it](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Can this be done to a set of csv files in a folder?

Comment: @user2500677 Yes.

Comment: Find below script and correct me where I am wrong.

`@echo off 
setlocal
if exist three.txt del three.txt 
set cnt=1
rem get the date "01/12/15"
for %%i in (*.csv) do (
if cnt>=1 (
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1-10 usebackq delims=," %%a in (`type "%%i"`) do ( 
  set _date=%%d
  goto :next
  )
:next
rem add the date to the end of every line and output to "three.txt"
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in (`type "%%i"`) do ( 
  echo %%a,%_date%>> three.txt
  )
)
 set /a cnt+=1
)
endlocal`

Comment: @user2500677 This is a new question. You should [accept this answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) and ask a new question. You can reference this one for context if it helps.