# Bat script for a set of csv files in a folder

Tags: windows, script, batch-file

[How to store a value in a variable and load that variable as a new column in a file using a batch script?](https://superuser.com/questions/1074751/how-to-store-a-value-in-a-variable-and-load-that-variable-as-a-new-column-in-a-f/1074775#1074775)

The above link is used to read a date field and write it to all the records in a csv file. I want it to be done for a set of csv files in a folder. Below is the script for the requirement, I want to know what is the mistake in the below script

```
@echo off 
setlocal if exist three.txt del three.txt 
set cnt=1 rem get the date "01/12/15" 
for %%i in (*.csv) do ( 
if cnt>=1 ( 
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1-10 usebackq delims=," %%a in (type "%%i") do ( 
set _date=%%d 
goto :next 
) 
:next 
rem add the date to the end of every line and output to "three.txt" 
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in (type "%%i") do ( 
echo %%a,%_date%>> three.txt 
) 
) 
set /a cnt+=1 
) 
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want it to be done for a set of csv files in a folder

Again, your batch file is broken in many different ways.

You need to learn how to debug your own batch files:

- See [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php) for some hints.
- To debug you also need to check the syntax of the commands your are using. See [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/).

Rather than spend time debugging your batch file, it is quicker for me to modify the batch file from my [answer to the linked question](https://superuser.com/a/1074775/337631) to answer your new question.

Use the following batch file (example.cmd):

```
@echo off 
setlocal 
if exist three.txt del three.txt 
for /r %%i in (*.csv) do ( 
  call :process_file %%i
  )
goto :eof

:process_file
  echo processing %1
  for /f "skip=5 tokens=1-10 usebackq delims=," %%a in (`type %1`) do ( 
    set _date=%%d 
    goto :next 
  )
:next 
  rem add the date to the end of every line and output to "three.txt" 
  for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in (`type %1`) do ( 
    echo %%a,%_date%>> three.txt 
    )
  ) 
endlocal
```

---

#### How do I write the results to the same csv file instead of the three.txt?

Use the following batch file (example.cmd):

```
@echo off 
setlocal 
for /r %%i in (*.csv) do ( 
  call :process_file %%i
  )
goto :eof

:process_file
  echo processing %1
  for /f "skip=5 tokens=1-10 usebackq delims=," %%a in (`type %1`) do ( 
    set _date=%%d 
    goto :next 
  )
:next 
  rem add the date to the end of every line and output to "three.txt" 
  for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in (`type %1`) do ( 
    echo %%a,%_date%>> three.txt 
    )
  )

  rem rename the file
  del %~nx1
  ren three.txt %~nx1 
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [call](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) - Call one batch program from another, or call a subroutine.

  - [del](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) - Delete one or more files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).
- [goto](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) - Direct a batch program to jump to a labelled line.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [ren](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) - Rename a file or files.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.

Comment: Thank u so much @DavidPostill. Request doing it in another way is how to store it in the same csv file instead of the three.txt?

Comment: @user2500677 Please don't keep changing the question. I've updated the answer for you this time.